# how to get more vertical spacing on a horizontal aligned asp.net tabstrip

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I have an asp.net tabstrip that is horizontally aligned.  Sometimes the tabs take up two rows and the bottom row seems like it is right on top of the top row. What properties do I need to use to get the second row away from the first?  We tried manually inserting a page break after    a certain number of tabs have been created in the code behind, but on smaller screen sizes the tabs don't stack very well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A screenshot or some example code would help, but it sounds like you need to set the `CssClass` attribute for each row, and add margins to the class:

```
.toprow {
    margin-bottom: 10px !important;
}
```